# Paste event for a DisplayObjectContainer not registered in AS3

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, copy-paste

I have a display object container and I am trying to add a paste event to it. But the event is not being registered. The documentation at liveDocs mentions that classes that derive from Interactive objects can dispatch paste event but I dont understand why it wouldnt work for me.

My app is not an AIR app, could it be a reason ?

Comment: is there anyone who can help me here, I tried adding event listener to a textField but even that didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

The livedocs also say "TextField objects do *not* dispatch clear, copy, cut, paste, or selectAll events. [...] However, other classes that extend the InteractiveObject class, including components built using the Flash Text Engine (FTE), can dispatch these events."

I'm also looking for a Event.PASTE from a TextField but haven't found a work around yet.

Does your DisplayObject have focus? Does it receive other events, such as the Keyboard events?

Comment: i believe it has focus because the keyboard events are registered properly. Only the Cntrl+C and Cntrl+V events are not registered. What you can do is to add a sprite object on top(or maybe below it) of ur textfield and listen for copy or paste events their. I havent tried it myself but it might work, just a thought.